# TypeScript Array: .map() is not a Function

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I searched for another question like this, but 99% of the other questions are dealing with an Observable, which I'm not. I have code that looks like this:

```
selectedItems: Item[] = null;
selectedDate: Date = null;

submitItems() {
    const itemObservables = this.selectedItems.map(item => {
        item.date = this.selectedDate;
        return this.itemService.putMovedItems(item)
    });

    return forkJoin(itemObservables);
}
```

In VSCode, there are no linter errors; this should be valid code. However, at runtime I get "TypeError: selectedItems.map is not a function".

When I debug, I notice that this.selectedItems says:

```
Object {0: Item, 1: Item, 2: Item, ...}
```

This caused me to suspect that when the property is set, it's not being set as an actual Array. So, I tried to cast by doing:

```
const items = <Array<Item>>this.selectedItems;
```

and then do the map on `items`, but I got the same runtime error. I'm not sure what's going on here.

Edit: For clarity's sake, `selectedItems` is set in the ngOnInit():

```
ngOnInit() {
    const selectedItems = this.itemService.selectedItems.getValue();
    this.selectedItems = {...selectedItems};
}
```

`this.itemService.selectedItems` is a `BehaviorSubject<Item[]>`.

Comment: Adding `<Array<Item>>` won't actually turn the object into an array, its just a cast to tell typescript to think of it as an array and doesn't effect the produced javascript at all. The problem is definitely that `selectedItems` is not being set to an array. Posting the code where it is set might be helpful.

Comment: Yeah, you were right. I was getting an Array-like back when I was expecting an array, so I needed to convert and didn't know how. I didn't know array-like was even a thing in TypeScript.

Comment: I thought as much. I see that you've posted your own answer using `Object.values`. I've also added an answer to clarify what was going wrong with the original code and providing alternate solutions to allow the `Item[]` type on `selectedItems` to be respected.

Comment: I actually like your solution better and it turns out that it will work; ngx-datatable WAS returning an array, I had just looked at it at the wrong point. The spread operator was indeed the problem, so I'm going to accept your answer once I finish testing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `<Array<Item>>` won't actually turn the object into an array, its just a cast to tell typescript to think of it as an array and doesn't effect the produced javascript at all.

The problem is that the spread operator you are using to clone your array is producing an generic object, not an array:

```
this.selectedItems = {...selectedItems};
```

The `{...obj}` syntax

> copies own enumerable properties from a provided object onto a new object. 
>   [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals)

So the resulting object has the length property and all the numbered properties of the array you passed in, but it is an object, not an array and so doesn't have the Array.prototype methods.

However, you can use the spread operator to clone an array, you just need to use square brackets to signify that you're creating an array:

```
this.selectedItems = [...selectedItems];
```

You can also clone an array using slice:

```
this.selectedItems = selectedItems.slice(0);
```